# Python pass ref int as parameter

Tags: python, com

tlb library in my python project through`win32com.client`. I've worked with many built in functions easily but one of the main functions get list of parameters that two of them is marked as `ref int`. When I try to pass python integer to the function I get `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352571, 'Type mismatch.', None, 5)` error, which is obviously because of some wrong parameters passed to the object.
This is my python code:

```
import sldworksPython as solidWorks
import sldconstPython as solidConst
import win32com.client


swApp: solidWorks.ISldWorks = win32com.client.Dispatch(solidWorks.SldWorks.CLSID)
swConst = solidConst.constants

fileName = "Assem Of Hinge.SLDASM"
docType = int(swConst.swDocASSEMBLY)
config = int(swConst.swOpenDocOptions_AutoMissingConfig)
error = int(swConst.swFileNotFoundError)
warning = int(swConst.swFileLoadWarning_AlreadyOpen)

print(type(error))

swApp.OpenDoc6(
    fileName,    
    docType,
    config,
    error,
    warning
)
```

and here is the openDoc6 function:

```
ModelDoc2 OpenDoc6(string FileName, int Type, int Options, string Configuration, ref int Errors, ref int Warnings);
```

this error is freaking me out I really don't want to use C# for this project. Thanks for your help

Comment: Clearly it doesn't like Python integers, which are quite different from C integers. I think you should not be converting all of those `swConst` values to Python integers.

Comment: @BoarGules I've tried not converting them but still the same issue.

Comment: I can't  find anything on `sldworksPython`. Is it possible that the module was written for Python 2, which had C-style integers? If it was last updated more than 5 years ago that is likely. If so, you might try https://pypi.org/project/pySW/, which is for Python >= 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @BoarGules, I've just downloaded a library for SW named pySW. I was wondering how the functions are working there so I've just checked them and understood how shall I pass an integer as reference to C# functions.

I add my solution below:

```
import sldconstPython as solidConst
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
import pySW



swApp: solidWorks.ISldWorks = win32com.client.Dispatch(solidWorks.SldWorks.CLSID)
swConst = solidConst.constants

fileName = "Assem Of Hinge.SLDASM"
docType = swConst.swDocASSEMBLY
docOpts = swConst.swOpenDocOptions_AutoMissingConfig
error = win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_BYREF | pythoncom.VT_I4, swConst.swFileNotFoundError)
warning = win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_BYREF | pythoncom.VT_I4, swConst.swFileLoadWarning_AlreadyOpen)

swApp.OpenDoc6(fileName, docType, docOpts, "", error, warning)
```

It was strange as VScode didn't suggest me any `pythoncom` constants. Anyway, hope this will help ppl who face such problem.

Comment: VSCode's hints typically don't work with `pythoncom`, the reason being that `pythoncom` objects are thin Python wrappers around VBA objects. The `pythoncom` objects know nothing about the VBA objects other than their entry points, and VSCode can't see through the wrappers.

Comment: Yea I understood the problem now. Thanks for your help @BoarGules . I wouldn't be able to solve my problem without your help.